# Connecting Visual Studio 2013 to Raspberry Pi MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on a project that requires a database, and I'd like to remotely host this database on my Raspberry Pi that I have hooked up to my home network. I can access the Pi from my web browser and from putty, but when I try to connect with Visual Studio using the IP address, it says that the server can't be found. Does anyone have any insight as to what the best way to connect a Raspberry Pi hosted MySQL database to Visual Studio 2013?
Thanks!

Comment: Can it be that the port is blocked? An old-school way of checking this would be to use telnet.

Comment: @Pawel it is not old school it is a very valid technique to quickly check if a port is open.

Comment: @Namphibian - I called it old school because telnet stopped being installed by default on Windows boxes like 6+ years ago (I think with Vista) and since he is trying to use VS he probably won't have it on this box...

Comment: @Pawel, Lol yeah  I agree apparently telnet is a security risk. Which makes me wonder why they still install IE by default? Sorry had to sneak that one in. Regardless I would agree to check the connectivity by doing a telnet port to the Pi